# Angular-ui-router : Got error when assign number to resolve's property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use angularjs v1.6.3. I got an error when assign a number to resolve's property of state.

```
.state('products-new', {
    url: "/rent/whats-new/",
    resolve: {
      pageType: 2, 
    }
    ...
}
```

This is the error message i have got :

> ## Error: ng:areq 
>   Bad Argument
>
> Argument 'fn' is not a function, got number

Can anyone explain to me why this happen ?

Comment: I believe (feel free for anyone to correct me) resolves should be functions. So your code should be `resolve:{pageType:function(){return 2}}`

Comment: @George thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, [Resolves](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) should either be a function which returns the value or a string to a service that gets injected. For more information look at the documentation I've linked above. So change your code to the below and all should work.

```
.state('products-new', {
    url: "/rent/whats-new/",
    resolve: {
        pageType: function () {
            return 2;
        },
    }
}
```